# why I make the android source cant't run in the nexus4

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

my phone is nexsu4. and version is 4.4.2

I get the source from Google server.

```
source build/envsetup.sh

lunch aosp_maguro

make -j4
```

then  I copy the wpa_supplicant to my nexus4 and reboot the phone.

but wlan can't run.

who can help me? thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maguro is the Galaxy Nexus, not the Nexus 4. If you are building for Nexus 4, you need to get the mako proprietary drivers from [Google's Proprietary Binaries](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers). Then use the

```
lunch aosp_mako-userdebug
```

to select mako as your device.

Comment: thx for your help. I download the `extract-qcom-mako.sh` file.   run it in the sourcedir ?

Comment: should be multiple sh files. run all of them and it will create a vendor folder for you. throw that into your build aosp root directory

Comment: but I have a question. I disassembly the `wpa_supplicant` in IDA. It seems have no wrong.  It is `armv7a` mode.Is it have any anti code for the license?  And ! I can have a result when I type `wpa_supplicant -version` in the shell.

Comment: @kings0527 I'm not sure what you're trying to do honestly. If this answer solved your original problem, I would move on and make a new question and describe what you are trying to do now if you want to get some fresh answers. It will be difficult to describe the problem you are having in comments.

Comment: sorry, my english is poor.  The question had solved by yoour help. very thx. My new question is - Why need to do this? How to download the proprietary drivers if I wanna run `wpa_supplicant` in samsung S3.

Comment: I can't understand what did `proprietary drivers` do .

Comment: @kings0527 If this solved your question, you should mark this answered and ask a new one (click the check box). As for your question on why you need the proprietary drivers, those are the binaries distributed by the hardware manufacturers so that Android knows how to work with the hardware it has.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know well the operate of the stackoverflow.  Now, you are the best answer. Very thanks!